# 2014 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2014 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I won't be running, as I can't be sufficiently active.  I'd rather make way for the many qualified candidates the site has cultivated over the past couple of years.  Congrats to all who guided this site through to this stage!

Comment: @NickC - Thanks for all your contributions and support! I really appreciate your help and guidance when I first came on-board and was getting up to speed.